# android service with repeating thread in background with partial wake lock

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, wakelock

I have a thread running in a service of an app that reads out data from a page that has been logged into with a webview before. That thread is working fine.

Now i would like to repeat this thread periodically, say once minute, even while the phone is asleep/screen off. I know i would probably have to go about it with wake_lock but i have no clue how.

I have 3 problems here. I tried to repeat the thread with while(true)sleep(60000).... but that stops the thread after the screen of the phone goes off. Is there a better way?

Then i would also like to compare the string count to zero. Meaning if string count is greater than zero do xxx.

Any help is very appreciated!

```
Thread downloadThread = new Thread() {                     
          public void run() {                                    
                Document doc;      
                doc = null;


            try {                 
                final String url = "https://xxx.xxx.xx";


                // -- Android Cookie part here --
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();

                String cookie = cm.getCookie(url);           

                // Jsoup uses cookies as "name/value pairs"
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://xxx.xxx.xx").cookie(url, cookie).get();

                Elements elements = doc.select("span.tabCount");
                String count = elements.first().text();



                Log.d(TAG, "wart"+(count));
                Log.d(TAG, "wartcookiedate:"+(cookie));





            } catch (IOException e) {                          
                e.printStackTrace();                           
            }                                                  
        }                                                      
    };                                                         
    downloadThread.start();
```

Here is my second try with the code below. When the user is already logged in it workds perfectly. My problem now is that on start of the app the string "count" will be returned null since the user is not logged in yet. Therefore an exception will be thrown which stops the entire scheduled Task Executor. Is there a way to just restart it if "count" is null?

```
scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    // This schedule a task to run every 10 seconds:

    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {

          Document doc;      
            doc = null;


            try {                 
                final String url = "https://xxx.xxx.xx";


                // -- Android Cookie part here --
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();

                String cookie = cm.getCookie(url); // returns cookie for url


                // Jsoup uses cookies as "name/value pairs"
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://xxx.xxx.xx").cookie(url, cookie).get();

                Elements elements = doc.select("span.tabCount");
                String count = elements.first().text();



                Log.d(TAG, "wart"+(count));
                Log.d(TAG, "wartcookiedate:"+(cookie));





            } catch (IOException e) {                          
                e.printStackTrace();                           
            }                                     


      }
    }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use an explicit thread with a `while` + `sleep` to simulate a timer. It's ugly and unnecessary. There are more elegant ways that automatically schedule tasks every x time units, like [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: thank you!! how can i go about it the the wake_lock and the string comparison?

Comment: @SunnySonic: You should try first and see if `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` has the same problem as your previous code.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. After reading a bit i could create that even in my main activity and would not necessarily need a separate service for that. will try it out and get back here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used your tip and it seems to work very nicely leaving me with another problem though. Please see my edit of the first post.

Comment: @SunnySonic: Why don't you just check if the string is null and do nothing in that case?

Comment: sorry me being so dumb. ;) but I'm pretty new to that stuff. mind giving me an example? I actually thought that is what the exception is doing already.

Comment: @SunnySonic: Which line is throwing the exception? The log? Because I don't see the `count` string being used anywhere else.

Comment: Might be that elements is null first and therefore count too since it cant connect to the webpage yet. for the moment im just using it to print out the value as a log. later i want to make some sort of notification from it. 
cant thank you enough for your help!

Comment: @SunnySonic: First I suggest you use a few logs for each object you are using to determine exactly which one is null.

Comment: thanks. all good now. after i restarted eclipse and change the lines Elements elements = doc.select("span.tabCount");
                String count = elements.first().text();                         to                                                                 String count = doc.select("span.tabCount").text();  all is working. thanks again!